# What kind of fish is on the picture?

Tags: species-identification, species, ichthyology

I saw these fish in a video at an art exhibition, I'd like to find out what kind they are.
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an Atlantic wolffish (*Anarhichas lupus*). It's a very characteristic fish, with the teeth, the long dorsal fin and the small back fin.

[image]

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlantic_wolffish